# Codeigniter error Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$members_id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this error message when running PHP Code Igniter project:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$members_id
>
> Filename: models/mtree.php
>
> Line Number: 33

In line 33 `($row->members_id)` refer to field in my database

```
VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($row->members_id) . ", " . $this->db->escape($left_parent) . ")";
```

My model function is:

```
function insert_to_right($direct_id='members_direct_id') {
        $left_parent = $this->get_right_parent('members_id');
        $row->members_direct_id = $left_parent;
        $row->members_spillover_id = $left_parent;
        $this->db->insert('ajmatrix_members_table', $row);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ayman_mot (child, parent)
        VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($row->members_id) . ", " . $this->db->escape($left_parent) . ")";
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: The error message says it..

Comment: Check if $row has members_id, like if(!empty($row->members_id)) ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code don't have the `members_id` property in row.

$row variable have only 2 properties:

```
    $row->members_direct_id = $left_parent;
    $row->members_spillover_id = $left_parent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your **Model** where you have the db select statement, for example:

> $this->db->select('field1, field2, field3, field4');

try and replace it with:

> $this->db->select('*');

Worked out for me, after battling it out for weeks through forums.
Though my initial mistake was putting the statement like this:

> $this->db->select('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');

~ Mistakes are the ones we make ~ (speaking for myself here, don't hit me ^_^ )
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining `$row->members_id` in your code - elsewhere you're referencing a members_direct_id - is that what you meant to use perhaps?